# Rigify rig does not generate a bone to control hand

Tags: rigging, rigify

I am using rigify and here to generate a hand rig but rigify doesn't generate a control bone for hand.
[image: Image about my problem with rigify]

Normally there should be a control bone to rotate hand like this(I think): https://youtu.be/WLBT-NCjxeA

Appreciate if you could help

Comment: Add an image of your original armature or share your Blend file and we might be able to help! You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: The missing red hand IK control is part of the arm. You probably don't have the needed arm bones/rig types since you only have a forearm and a hand. I've just check it. The rig type *limbs.arm* is assigned to the upper_arm bone which you don't have. How have you created the meta-rig for the hand? Try to add the *limbs.arm* sample (*Edit* mode, Armature > *Object Data Properties* tab > *Rigify > Samples*)